# Where is the documentation for aura:handler?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, event, aura

I can find some reference to it in the documentation, but I find it odd that I cannot find specific documentation on aura:handler. Does it exist and I just cannot find it or does it just not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated 02/07/2022**

All of the Aura docs can be found in the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm). Click on the menu to the left and watch it expand. `Aura:Handler` is discussed under: Communicating with Events > Application Events > [Handling Application Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling.htm).

Comment: There does not seem to be any direct documentation at the link you provided, but I did find some good stuff in the [github repo](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura_oss.pdf).

Comment: @notthehoff Usually for every tag there is documentation with all the possible attributes. For some reason, there is none for this tag. Weird.

Comment: No docs for aura:handler.

Comment: The original link above eventually takes you to GitHub and the PDF at https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura_oss.pdf.

Comment: This is maddening. I'm having such a difficult time finding documentation on `aura:handler` and the list of events, and this answer does not help at all, as it just points to general documentation that doesn't even exist anymore. I do realize this is an older post - can we get an update?